# Not able to install and use SwiftyXMLParser library via pod

Tags: xml, swift, xcode

I am trying to install and use **SwiftyXMLParser** (https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser) via a podfile. The pod file installs the library without any issues but as soon as I use the import statement in my source code and build the project I get bunch of errors along with the message `"No such module SwiftyXMLParser"`

I am using **Xcode 7** and **Swift 2.3** and my podfile looks like this.

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ApplePaySwag' do

  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ApplePaySwag
  pod 'SwiftyXMLParser', :git => 'https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser.git'

  target 'ApplePaySwagTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

put ``pod 'SwiftyXMLParser', :git => 'https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser.git'` before the

```
 # Pods for ApplePaySwag
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify "swift2.3" branch. Because SwiftyXMLParser on Cocoapods supports only Swift 3.

```
pod 'SwiftyXMLParser', :git => 'https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser.git', :branch => "swift2.3"
```